# Javascript Will Not Run When Certain CSS Class is on the Input Field

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am not very proficient in CSS or JavaScript yet and need some help. I am doing maintenance on a jsp page that has an input field which acts as a parameter in some search functionality. I added a JavaScript function that allows the user to press the enter key and fire off the search functionality, using the "onkeypress" event. The input field has three CSS classes on it. One of those CSS classes is keeping the JavaScript function from being called. I know this because removing the class allows the JavaScript to run. As soon as I put it back, the JavaScript won't run.

Here is the JavaScript, the CSS class (.personSearch) and the input field respectively.

```js
function searchKeyPress(e) {
 if(typeof e == 'undefined' && window.event) {
  e = window.event; 
 }
 if(e.keyCode == 13){
  document.getElementById('searchButton').click();
 }
}
```

```css
.personSearch {
    background-image: url(./../images/icons/personSearch.png);
    background-position:center right;
    background-repeat:no-repeat
}
```

```html
<input class="fillWidth personSearch allowManualInput" 
    name="scrName" 
    id="personSearch-scr" 
    type="text" 
    onkeypress="searchKeyPress(event);"/>
```

Like I said above, when I actually remove the `personSearch` class from the input field, the JavaScript runs great. However, when I leave it, the JavaScript won't fire.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. When I hit enter, the click event triggers. Can you reproduce this in a jsFiddle?

Comment: Yeah, let me put it together.

Comment: @j08691 I can't recreate this in a jsFiddle. It seems to work just fine there. I did end up creating a new CSS class in my project with the exact same contents, but just with a different name and now it works fine.

Must be some factor in the project that's causing this...

Comment: @j08691 fyi, here is the jsFiddle I created [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dwd4382n/1/). Like I said, it works fine so I'm not sure what's up with the code.

Comment: Probably another script is binding a click event handler to elements with that class, and that conflicts with what you are trying to add … anyway, with only the snippet you have shown this is not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because there is no element with an id="searchButton" defined in the HTML code.

```
<button id="searchButton" onclick="alert('here');">Click</button>
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m7qov85g/